# What causes 'Both DataSource and DataSourceID are defined on 'DataListCity'. Remove one definition' error?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am getting this error

> "Both DataSource and DataSourceID are defined on 'DataListCity'.  Remove one definition."

This is the code from my Masterpage that is causing the error

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataListCity" runat="server" Width="100%" 
    onitemcommand="DataListCity_ItemCommand" CellPadding="4" 
    ForeColor="#333333" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">

    <ItemTemplate>
        CityId:
        <asp:Label ID="CityIdLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CityId") %/>
        <br />
        CityName:
        <asp:Label ID="CityNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CityName")%>' />
        <br />
        <br />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>

<asp:SqlDataSource
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:HotelConnString %>" 
    ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server"   
    SelectCommand="SELECT [CityId], [CityName], [Description] FROM [Categories]">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: Have you added this in code behind as well ?

Answer (score 0):

Remove your binding code from cs if you have written in code behind because you can bind only by code behind or from design not both at same time

Remove these lines from code behind

```
DataListCity.DataSource=somesource;
DataListCity.DataBind();
```